# JQuery Autocomplete not narrowing

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Example data:

```
var data = [{label:"Jonathan Montiel",value:"28465"},{label:"Jackson C. Gomes",value:"5145692"}];
```

Autocomplete code:

```
$("#tagName").autocomplete({        
            source: function(request, response) {
                response(data);
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#tagName" ).val( ui.item.label); 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

When I type in input with id #tagName, autocomplete options show but do not reduce as I type, any letter input leaves same autocomplete result e.g. typing `ja` leaves both options showing.

Is there a glaring error?

Comment: using jQuery UI autocomplete?

Comment: @user1737909 Yeah, using the standard autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#tagName").autocomplete({        
            source: data //updated here
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#tagName" ).val( ui.item.label); 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

works fine for me with `jquery 1.9.1` and `UI`
You can pass in the json data directly.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag36F/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a large external data set.  I solved it by loading the data into a local variable and using the variable as the source in the autocomplete function.